# Should cookie be sent in Request header for POST when simulating the process of logging into a website?

Tags: c#, http, cookies, authentication, httpwebrequest

In the simulation of logging into a website with C#.

(a banking website [specifically](https://web17.secureinternetbank.com/EBC_EBC1961/EBC1961.ashx?WCI=Process&WCE=Request&RID=3000&RTN=122243224&MFA=2) ),

Should there be any cookie expected in the POST request `HttpWebRequest` (if this C# simulation parallels the process of a web browser visiting the site for its first time and logging in)? Do I need to include `HttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieString)` or should the cookie be omitted (since it's a first visit)? According to my understanding, a web browser receives its first cookie after its first visit; the browser doesn't have any cookie to submit when it requests for a website for its first visit. However, the browser will be able to submit cookies for its second visit (and third, etc).

Comment: depends on the site, doesn't it? if the site disallows direct first-time submission to the login url, then you'd have to hit the site at least once to get whatever cookies/sessions it needs set up, THEN do your login request.

Comment: It's exceedingly unlikely that the designers of the site anticipated that the first hit on the website would be a `POST`, as it's not possible to issue a `POST` from a bookmark or the address bar. They can assume that a `GET` preceeded the `POST`. I don't really want to follow your link, but I'd be surprised if there weren't cookies set on the first (`GET`) visit to the page in the browser that would need to be copied to your `POST` in order for the `POST` to succeed... for instance cookies to mitigate cross site request forgeries.